# How should I save the current refrence to a parent node in JSON format?

Tags: javascript

I have a tree json format like this one:

```
$scope.myjson = [
                   {id: "1", name: "a"},
                   {id: "2", name: "b"},
                   {id: "3", name: "c", children: [
                                   {id: "4", name: "d"},
                                   {id: "5", name: "e", children: [
                                                        {id: "6", name: "f"}] 
                    }]}
               ];
```

Here is the problem:
If I am currently at `myjson[2].children[1].children[0]` I would like to jump to his parent without looking or searching all the data to find it. How should I save the refrence to 'myjson[2].children[1]' so I can return to that parent right away.

I'm having difficult to understand how to save the currentNode I am selecting in tree and how will be the easy and fast way to go back for his parent and than his parent and so on until getting back to the root.

My tree is going to be flat, which means you don't see all the hieracy just the nodes inside of the previus node you click on. I will have a "back" button to return to the parent node somehow. Later on I want to save the breadcrumbs that are the path to that node I'm seeing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an explicit reference to a parent node, the only way is to walk the tree and search for the parent. Sounds inefficient, but should be fast enough for small trees.

```js
$scope = {}
$scope.tree = [
                   {id: "1", name: "a"},
                   {id: "2", name: "b"},
                   {id: "3", name: "c", children: [
                                   {id: "4", name: "d"},
                                   {id: "5", name: "e", children: [
                                                        {id: "6", name: "f"}] 
                    }]}
               ];



function parent(tree, id, prev) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        var node = tree[i];
     if (node.id == id)
             return prev;
        if (node.children) {
            var p = parent(node.children, id, node);
            if (p)
                return p;
        }
    }
}
  
  
p = parent($scope.tree, 6)
document.write(JSON.stringify(p))
```

Comment: Probably the tree stracture will be build dynamicly. first you will see only first level tree. Click on nodeX will bring its children from server and so on. I am thinking what I can add to the json that may help me go back faster. The tree can get really big.

Comment: Ok, then store the current "path" as an array. In you example, if node `id=6` is selected, the path will be `[2,1,0]`.

Comment: How do I convert this array into a real path? I need loop that will end up with tree[2].children[1].children[0]

Comment: Looping the array length and save each iteration as what? Don't understand how to create the path and not the objects on the way.

Comment: @AvivM: when navigating the tree, push the last selected node's index into the path, when going back, pop it. To obtain a pointer to an object, yes, loop it: `for(obj=tree,i=0;i<path.length;i++)obj=obj[path[i]];`